# @SceneStorage for non-value types, like ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to keep the state of my SwiftUI Mac app which may have multiple windows open at the same time. `@SceneStorage` would work if I kept the state in `struct` but I have my state in (multiple) `ObservableObject`. How to implement the manual saving and restoring of multiple windows' state when the user quits and relaunch the app?

Minized version where one value is stored, but the `ObservableObject`'s value not:

```swift
class MyObservable : ObservableObject {
    @Published var value = 0.5
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("app") var appValue = 0.5
    @SceneStorage("scene") var sceneValue = 0.5
    @StateObject var observable = MyObservable()
    
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $appValue) // shared value for all the windows
        Slider(value: $sceneValue) // individual values preserved for each window
        Slider(value: $observable.value) // no values preserved
    }
}

@main
struct scenestorageApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make your ObservableObject codable, store it in UserDefaults on change and load on App start.

Comment: But how to know which window should have which state? How to pass the loaded object(s) to the window(s)? All I have a 'WindowGroup' with unknown number of instances.

Comment: although maybe I just do what you suggested with a single stored value. The values of SceneStorage gets preserved between a force quit and relaunch, but a simple app quit destroys its state, which is not what i want.

Comment: state shouldn't be in objects in SwiftUI

Comment: @malhal: Easier said than done. My state is modified outside of the SwiftUI as well - like networking and other system events. I need to have a single source of truth and a way to modify it from various parts of the code, outside of UI. Some of the code could be crammed inside a View just to access the state, although have nothing to do with the view, but not all of them, because these actors also have states themselves. I cannot keep all the states of the app in a top level struct or something. Do I miss something?